# How to add a key conditionaly in JavaScript object in the given code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating an object which has few keys to it .

```
processData = memoize(
    ({
      data,
      group
    }:EnumValues): Array<ITypeData> => {
      return _.map(test, (test: ITest) => ({
        id: test.Id,
        name: test.Name,
        code: test.Code,
}))
```

Here I am creating the object. Here there is a key called `code`, so if I don't want to have this key if there is no `group` data available or that is not sent. as this `processData` function is getting called from two places where from one place it gets that `group` data and from another not getting.

I tried:

```
code : test && test.Code
```

but still it doesn't work. Is there another way to handle this?

Comment: Please keep in mind, if one of the answers works for you, please mark them as the answer to help other peeps in the community to find their solution easier if they facing the same issue. You can do this by using grey marks (tick) beside answers (you can only choose one), for more information please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a **spread operator** to achieve such a thing, so the output of your code should be something like this:

```js
processData = memoize(
    ({
      data,
      group
    }:EnumValues): Array<ITypeData> => {
      return _.map(test, (test: ITest) => ({
        id: test.Id,
        name: test.Name,
        ...(test.Code && {code: test.Code})
}))
```

**NOTE:** The spread operator here is actually work as same as `Object.assign()`, so whenever the source be like `null` or `undefined` it won't apply it to the target.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
processData = memoize(
    ({
      data,
      group
    }:EnumValues): Array<ITypeData> => {
      return _.map(test, (test: ITest) => {
          return test ? {
            id: test.Id,
            name: test.Name,
            code: test.Code,
        } : {
              id: test.Id,
              name: test.Name,
          }
      })
    })
```